# Read a file that's actively being written

Tags: unix, filesystems

I am downloading a large file via FTP so that I can process the file on my local system. The program that processes the file reads the file line by line in a single pass, creating two new files from the original.

Would it be possible to start processing the file before it is completely downloaded? What are the potential issues with this?

**Note**: I'm not really worried about the program reaching the end of the file before it's done downloading--the file is being downloaded more quickly than the program can process the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, if the program reads data sequentially from start. (Some, such as `unzip`, attempt seek to the end of the file first.)

Comment: `unzip` does so *not* because of compression, but because of the way Zip files are structured: with all file metadata at the end. Stream-compression programs, such as `gzip` or `xz`, do not work this way and can deal with actively-written files.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the file is not compressed you can try the following on Linux:

```
wget -O - www.fileserver.com/file.ext | tee outputfile.out | ./someprogram
```

`-O -` will cause `wget` to output the file to `stdout` which will then be piped to `someprogram`  while `tee` will save a copy of the `wget` output to `outputfile`.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be possible to start processing the file before it is completely downloaded?

yes

> What are the potential issues with this?

When reaching EOF - how to determine if it's really EOF or if the reader was just faster than the receiver and it should just wait a second before retrying the read?

Solutions to this would be:

- use timeouts - if the file size does not change anymore for a couple of minutes, the transfer may be considered as complete. I don't like this solution since one never knows, if the transfer was terminated ok or if the connection got lost.
- try to get the file size beforehand - if using an ftp server one can usually perform a 'dir' command to get the file size before downloading. This value may be passed to the reader program
- make the download script to create a 'transfer complete' file which the reader-program may check when it encounters EOF.

> Note: I'm not really worried about the program reaching the end of the file before it's done downloading--the file is being downloaded more quickly than the program can process the data.

You should - really! What if the network connection is slower than usual just because of some other transfers going on? Would it be ok to loose data in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good candidate for pipelining. Use an FTP client that writes to standard output have the splitting program read from standard input.